How to fetch secret values for K8s environment variables using GCP Secret Store CSI Driver
I have a requirement to fetch secrets stored in GCP Secret Manager and use them in my GKE Kubernetes pods. I am using the GCP Secret Store CSI driver to achieve this. While I am able to successfully establish the connection and retrieve the secrets, I am facing an issue with retrieving specific key values from the secret and assigning them to environment variables in the Kubernetes pods.
I have successfully set up a similar configuration in AWS using the CSI driver, where I can retrieve specific key-value pairs. However, when performing the same setup in GCP, I am unable to retrieve just the key-value pair. Instead, the entire secret JSON is being retrieved.
For example, if my secret is: {"admin_user":"test-admin","admin_password":"password"}
I expect the environment variable ADMIN_USER to have the value test-admin. But currently, it is taking the whole secret JSON value instead: ADMIN_USER={"admin_user":"test-admin","admin_password":"password"}.
How can I configure the GCP Secret Store CSI driver to retrieve specific key values and assign them to environment variables in Kubernetes pods?
Below is the secretProviderClass definition:
---
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: test-secret
spec:
  provider: gcp
  parameters:
    secrets: |
      - resourceName: "projects/<project-id>/secrets/testpassword/versions/latest"
        path: admin.txt
    objects: |
      - objectName: "testpassword"
        objectType: secretsmanager
        jmesPath:
          - path: "admin_user"
            objectAlias: "admin_user"
          - path: "admin_password
            objectAlias: "admin_password"
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: testpassword
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - objectName: admin.txt
      key: admin_user
    - objectName: admin.txt
      key: admin_password

Pod definition:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceAccountName: app-sa
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
    name: mypod
    env:
      - name: "ADMIN_USER"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: "testpassword"
            key: admin_user
      - name: "ADMIN_PASSWORD"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: "testpassword"
            key: admin_password
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/secrets"
        name: vol-secret
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: vol-secret
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: "test-secret"


see: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-gcp/issues/229

I tried to replicate the same configuration as yours and ended up fetching the entire JSON instead of the specific value. Check this existing public feature request and feel free to upvote on the feature to prioritize it accordingly.
For additional reference regarding the issue, you may refer to Extract JSON key-value pairs from secrets.

I ended up using external-secrets instead of CSI driver to fetch the specific key-value pairs.
